# Запись в файл перед уже записанным текстом

Tags: c, файлы

Итак, есть текст, к примеру: "я учусь в школе", который записывается в файл в программе. Нужно записать дополнительное слово "хорошей" перед словом школа (в этой же программе). Если пытаюсь это сделать с помощью `fprinf`, то слово школа просто затирается. Как сделать это не затирая слова, а сдвигая их вправо?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
FILE *fp;

if ((fp = fopen ("skul.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
    printf ("ERROR of open file skul.txt\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fprintf (fp, "i lern in skul");


if (fclose (fp) != 0) {
    printf ("ERROR of exit from file skul.txt\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((fp = fopen ("skul.txt", "r+")) == NULL) {
    printf ("ERROR of open file skul.txt\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fseek (fp, 10L, SEEK_SET);

fprintf (fp, "good ");

if (fclose (fp) != 0) {
    printf ("ERROR of exit from file skul.txt\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Копировать в другой файл, осуществляя вставку в нужном месте. Затем переименовать новый файл (в исходный).

Comment: В файле нет режима раздвигания существующей информации. Так что только копировать данные в промежуточный файл и потом переименовывать файлы. И да, школа пишется "school" а не "skul".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта, можешь попробовать при записи поменять w на w+, даст возможность дополнения файла.2й вариант: считать предложение до нужного символа, потом считать от этого символа до конца , получишь 2 массива char затем добавляешь свое слово и перезаписываешь в файл, чуть сложнее, но точно сработает.